# Is GeForce GTS 250 not enough to play NFS Hot Pursuit (2010)?

Tags: graphics-card, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

My PC specs:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E6600 2.4 GHz
- 3 GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTS 250 1 GB
- GeForce driver version 258.96
- 1680x1050 Native Resolution LCD Monitor
- Windows 7 Ultimate

According to [this website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Hot_Pursuit_%282010_video_game%29#Marketing_and_release), my PC specs are more than capable of handling more that what are the recommended specs to play NFS: Hot Pursuit. In practice, that's not the case. I'm forced to use the following graphics settings to maintain the minimum frame rate at which I'm comfortable to play:

- 1440x900 resolution
- Shadow: None
- High Resolution Texture: Off

I'm missing a great deal of graphics for this game. I've played Mafia II and StarCraft II at the highest visual settings with no frame rate lagging problems. Actually, this is the first game I've encountered that has frame rate lagging problems with the GeForce GTS 250.

Any idea why this could happen? What can I do to increase frame rate with the highest graphics settings?

Note: In the background I use Avira AntiVirus and the Windows built-in firewall. I don't think this causes the frame rate to lag, however, as they were turned on while I played Mafia II / StarCraft II and all the other games.

Comment: Perhaps you need a driver update?

Comment: @RCIX: I'll check. but from my experience, i believe that won't help much.

Comment: I have a GTX 295, and I am also struggling to get a nice FPS. I think it's just a very graphically-demanding game.

Comment: Your CPU is approx. 4 years old.  Maybe NFS:HP is just more CPU bound than the recommended specs imply.  Speaking of which, what mobo are you using?

Comment: @MBraedley: What is mobo?

Comment: I have: EVGA GeForce GTS 250 (1G GDDR3) Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.0GHz NVIDIA nForce 750i SLI ATX Intel Motherboard 4G RAM - 2 x OCZ Platinum 2GB (2 x 1GB) DDR2 1066 (PC2 8500) I have no problem playing NFS:HP on 32-bit Vista (SP2) with full detail at 1920x1200.

Comment: Motherboard or (more politically correct) mainboard.

Comment: @MBraedley: ASUS P5B-VM.

Comment: @tergiver hmm. i just don't get it. what am i missing. :(

Comment: Wait, what? The official system requirements (reproduced on Wikipedia) recommend a 2.6 Ghz E6700 and you have a 2.4 Ghz E6600. Your system *isn't* "more than capable".

Comment: @Lee: i don't think this will make any difference.

Comment: "..StarCraft II at the highest visual settings with no frame rate lagging problems." I most sincerely doubt that. I have a Core 2 Quad @ 3GHz and a Radeon HD 4870 (which is about 3-4 times more performant than a GTS 250) and it had trouble with the higher settings when I turned 2xAA on. A smooth framerate starts for me at 45 FPS yours may vary, of course.

Comment: @Bora, 30 FPS is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deactivating my WLAN Card solved the problem.**

I'm running the game fine on my Alienware M11x with an Intel U7300 at 2x 1.73Ghz with
4Gb RAM and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 335M at maximum resolution and full details, so I don't think it's your processor/RAM/motherboard.

But when I first installed the game, I had bad problems with FPS drops. It was like the game nearly stopped (2FPS or less) every 60 seconds, and after a few seconds more, everything was fine again.

So I started to diagnose the system (quite like proposed  by blesh) and found a Windows  service that detects performance, and from there worked out the solution. It sounds strange, but works on a M15x as well! It seems the scan for available access points is what causes the game to lag, especially when you're not connected.

Maybe this bugfix will solve your problems too!

Comment: mine one is not laptop. i connect with internet using a wimax transceiver. that transceiver is connected to my build in lan card of MB. i tried disabling LAN and it 'seems' to improve the frame rate. i need to try out more races though.

however, there are certain points in certain stages where frame rate always drops! it looks like a graphics card issue but how it could be!

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is a little old, but **I'm pretty sure it's the memory.**

**Try starting the game**, then **Windows+TAB out** of it and go to your **Task Manager** under the **performance** tab and check to see **how much memory** is available. If it looks like you're using most (or almost all) of your memory; that's probably where your problem is at.

I highly doubt it's your graphics card.

3GB of RAM is rather light for a gaming rig running Windows 7. If you can up the ram on the cheap, I'd try that.

Comment: Only useful if he's running a 64 bit version (doesn't say in the question).  If he's running 32 bit, then he's already hit the limit since the GPU has 1GB of memory.

Comment: +1 very true, I had forgotten there are still luddites with 32-bit OSes out there.

Comment: yep, i'm using 32 bit Windows.

Comment: @blesh: how is this possible that increasing resolution will eat up my RAM where there is 1 GB of memory available in graphics card?

Comment: Not everything graphical that is being used is held in your graphics card's memory. The more detailed the graphics the more pieces of information that need to be tracked. Most of the raw data about polygons, positioning and models will be held in your RAM, the Graphics Card memory is primarily used for caching, buffering and processing of that data into something you can view. Think of it this way Video Card memory is for rendering, System memory is for everything else.

Comment: Regardless, with 32-bit windows, you're not going to be able to put anymore RAM in your machine.

Comment: @blesh: with everything maxed out, i launched a rapid response. the task manager showed 1.7 GB used.

Comment: 1.7GB used total? or just for the game? If total, then I guess RAM isn't  your problem.

Comment: @blesh: total. btw, that was because firefox was opened. after i close firefox, it came down to 1.48 GB.

Comment: Anyhow, I highly doubt it's the graphics card unless it's defective. It seems more like you don't have enough cowbell in the memory or CPU department. Most likely memory. The only way to remedy that would be to install Windows 64-bit and then upgrade your memory. I have a three year old Quad Core with 6GB of RAM and an ANCIENT graphics card and I run the latest and greatest games just fine.